# Can I write a custom validation error message that includes object data?

Tags: django

I know that when I create a model for say 'Jobs' I can set it to unique and set a custom message that's like "This job number is taken."  But was wondering is if I could give a validation error that give specific information about the model that's taken.

Such as: "This job number is taken and is associated with Client A." Where Client A would be retrieved from the job model.

Comment: You can subclass `ValidationError` and redefine any behavior you like, for example in separate `my_custom_exceptions.py` file. And then import your custom exception and raise (or reraise depending on situation) it where you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

name = 'foo'
title = 'bar'
try:
    Model.objects.create(name=name, title=title)
except ValidationError:
    "Name: {}, title: {} already taken.".format(name, title)
```

Comment: @Sayse, that's just a boilerplate example of how to show a custom error message based upon the current scope at the time the error is raised, and how to pass variables to an error message.